# The namespace or module 'Lab2' is not defined

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have looked at many similar questions and searched google for a few hours and I am getting nowhere.

I am trying to access my binary tree module which is in my Tree.fs file from my Program.fs file and in the explorer window I have moved the Tree.fs file above the Program.fs file as suggested in almost all of the other similar questions but this is till not working for me.

My Tree.fs file

```
namespace Lab2

type Elem = System.IComparable

type Tree = E | T of Tree * Elem * Tree

module BinaryTree =
    let emptyTree = E

    let rec add = function
                    | x, E -> T(E, x, E)
                    | x, T(a, y, b) when x < y -> T(add(x, a), y, b)
                    | x, T(a, y, b) when y < x -> T(a, y, add(x, b))
                    | _, s -> s

    let rec addList = function
                        | [], T(a, y, b) -> T(a, y, b)
                        | x::xs, T(a, y, b) when x < y -> addList(xs, T(add(x, a), y, b))
                        | x::xs, T(a, y, b) when y < x -> addList(xs, T(a, y, add(x, b)))
                        | _, s -> s


    let rec preorder = function
                        | T(a, y, b) when a <> E -> y::preorder a
                        | T(a, y, b) when b <> E -> y::preorder b
                        | _ -> []

    let rec inorder = function
                        | T(a, y, b) when a <> E -> y::inorder a
                        | T(a, y, b) when b <> E -> y::inorder b
                        | _ -> []

    let rec postorder = function
                        | T(a, y, b) when b <> E -> y::preorder b
                        | T(a, y, b) when a <> E -> y::preorder a
                        | _ -> []

    let rec treeToString = function
                            | T(a, y, b) when a <> E -> "(node " + y.ToString() + treeToString a
                            | T(a, y, b) when b <> E -> y.ToString() + treeToString b + ")"
                            | _ -> "Empty"
```

My Program.fs file

```
module Lab2.Program

open Lab2.BinaryTree

let tree = addList([5; 2; 1; 6; 7], emptyTree);;

let inorder_tree = inorder(tree);;

let char_tree = addList(['e';'b';'a';'f';'g'], emptyTree);;

let inorder_char_tree = inorder(char_tree);;

let print = treeToString(char_tree);;
```

I have tried not using the Lab2 namespace in both of my files and instead just using both files as modules but this still gives me the same error.

I have no blue or red lines in my code, no errors untill I debug

The error only happens on the following line

```
let tree = addList([5; 2; 1; 6; 7], emptyTree);;
```

So when debugging it looks like this

```
Program.fs(66,6): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Lab2' is not defined
> val inorder_tree : Elem list = []
> val char_tree : Tree = E
> val inorder_char_tree : Elem list = []
> val print : string = "Empty"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile and run the project, there is no error. Based on your results, I guess you manually copied contents of two files into F# Interactive except the first lines with namespace and module declaration. In this case, `Lab2` namespace wasn't known by F# Interactive hence the error message. A quick fix is to change

```
open Lab2.BinaryTree
```

to

```
open BinaryTree
```

It works on both `fsc` and `fsi` because `Program` and `BinaryTree` modules share the parent namespace `Lab2`.

However, you are confused between running the project and executing it in F# Interactive. A common solution is to create a `Tree.fsx` file and load corresponding modules in it:

```
#load "Tree.fs"    
open Lab2.BinaryTree

let tree = addList([5; 2; 1; 6; 7], emptyTree);;
let inorderTree = inorder(tree);;
let charTree = addList(['e';'b';'a';'f';'g'], emptyTree);;
let inorderCharTree = inorder(charTree);;
let print = treeToString(charTree);;
```